# Handling special characters and Serialization Exceptions in ASP.NET Web API XML response

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xmlserializer

I made ASP.NET Web API to use XmlSerializer over its default `DataContractSerializer` using the following configuration changes.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.Indent = true
```

### Xml Serialization Problem :

The JSON response of the Web API works fine for value given below but fails when an XML is requested.

[image]

**What I tried :** Adding SupportedEncodings to the XMLSerializer using

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter
                   .SupportedEncodings.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter
                   .SupportedEncodings.Add(new UnicodeEncoding());
```

### Handling Exceptions :

I tried catching the serialization exception by adding a `ExceptionFilterAttribute`

```
public class ErrorHandlingFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(
                   HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
           ....handle exception
    }
}
```

and registering the filter as

```
config.Filters.Add(new ErrorHandlingFilter());
```

the filters' `OnException` method is invoked when the ApiController's action throws an explicit exception, NOT when I get the serialization exception?

I have two part question

1. How can I avoid having issues with encoding the special characters in the response?
2. How can I catch these serialization exception.

Comment: I do not have complete answer for `1.`, but you need not clear the encodings as you are currently doing. You can just send the appropriate `Accept-Charset:utf-16` header here to achieve what you are doing. Also for `2.`, you will not be able to catch serialization exceptions in filters because the serialization happens way below in the host layers and past the exception filters.  May be I am doing wrong, but I tried with the characters you mentioned and didn't notice any error...could you share more info?

Comment: I guess when I copy pasted the stuff it removed the illegal characters got replace. I added a screenshot of the illegal characters, Donno if they can be reproduced easily.